# Netbeans - Can not install jdk 1.9.0 Build b53

Tags: netbeans, java-9

I'm trying to install jdk 1.9.0 early release package to be used with NetBeans 8. I realized that jdk is installed without private jre (there is no jre folder inside of jdk1.9.0 folder). And Netbeans don't work . In Java Platform Manager after selecting jdk1.9 field under Class tab contains no platform classpaths.See picture below.

[image]

jre1.9.0 folder is installed only as a seperated folder.
What can I do about it so I could compile and run my programs?

Comment: I don't think that Netbeans 8 is compatible with Java 9 - you probably need to use the latest dev version.

Comment: Would be easier to directly download the bundle : https://netbeans.org/downloads/jdk9-branch/2015-06-18/

Answer (score 0):

There will not be jre folder in JDK 9, as it is restructured. Plus you don't really need it as JDK has all files to compile and execute code.

As internal files of JDK and format are changed too, any IDE will not work, until it is updated to Java 9 support.

Answer (score 0):

***[NetBeans9.0](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/NetBeans+9.0+-+New+and+Noteworthy)*** is planned to be supporting JDK9 and JPMS.

You can though [get started](http://wiki.netbeans.org/JDK9Support#Getting_Started) to use Java9 modules with the Early Access build of the same.

There is a confluence wiki to keep track of the [new and noteworthy features](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/NetBeans+9.0+-+New+and+Noteworthy) marked to be exposed with the GA release of NetBeans.